# Add Project Custom Fields in Task List

Tags: sharepoint-online, project-online

I want to create a Project Dashboard using 'Sharepoint List', for this purpose i need to have certain Project Level fields to be added to my list to show data. Is there any possibility i can get project level fields in my task list or a custom list?

I am using Project Online.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way in SharePoint Online to read the value of "Project Level" from Project Online into a lookup field in SharePoint list.